# Cakephp Mongodb Print array, within array, within array, using nested forloops

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

The goal is to print out data from my database, through my view.ctp file, and be able to view it in my local host.

Here's the data I am working with:

```
array(
    'DataWriteError' => array(
        'modified' => object(MongoDate) {
            sec => (int) 1507762384
            usec => (int) 402000
        },
        'created' => object(MongoDate) {
            sec => (int) 1507762384
            usec => (int) 402000
        },
        'errors' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'index' => (int) 13370,
                'code' => (int) 11000,
                'message' => 'E11000 duplicate key error index: live_system.599c4ec3-0e24-408d-b8a6-067445404121.$Refcode_1 dup key: { : "VA1394315696" }'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'index' => (int) 14987,
                'code' => (int) 11000,
                'message' => 'E11000 duplicate key error index: live_system.599c4ec3-0e24-408d-b8a6-067445404121.$Refcode_1 dup key: { : "VA1394315697" }'
            )
        ),
        'campaign_id' => '59dea09d103fb4cb428fdef2',
        'id' => '59dea0d0bed1ec43d21cf65b'
    )
)
```

I have everything else displayed other than ERRORS. Errors has two arrays within it and I cannot for the life of me figure out where my code is wrong.

Here is my code to echo to view:

```
<td><?php foreach ($this->request->data['DataWriteError']['errors'] as $i => $item);
                    foreach ($item as $e => $etem) {
                        echo $this->request->data['DataWriteError']['errors']['index']['errors']['message'][$i];
                echo $this->request->data['DataWriteError']['errors']['index']['code']['message'][$e];
            } ?></td>
```

Not sure where I am going wrong. If there are any ideas, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried blow:

```
foreach ($this->request->data['DataWriteError']['errors'] as $i => $item) {
  echo $item['message'];
}
```

Comment: I actually literally just found a solution and made adjustments to get the result I wanted.

<td>
    <?php foreach ($this->request->data['DataWriteError']['errors'] as $i => $item) : ?>
     <?php echo $item['index']; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </td>